# Sending data from jquery ajax and receiving data from php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am having an issue with Jquery Ajax and PHP. I am trying to send data from my script to a php file which should handle the data further. But I am not getting any response from the php...

The html:

```
<form id="form-comment">
   <textarea id="popup-text" name="comment-text" placeholder="Skriv din kommentar her"></textarea>
   <input id="popup-close" type="button" value="Annuller"/>
   <input id="popup-ok" type="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>
```

The Jquery:

```
$('#form-comment').submit(function(event){
var comment = $('#popup-text').val()
var c_pdf = $('#current-pdf').attr('data')
var pdf_array = c_pdf.split("/")
var post_data = pdf_array[1].trim() + " " + pdf_array[2].slice(0,-4)

$.ajax({
    url: 'php/handler-comment.php',
    type: "post",
    data: post_data,
    succes: function(response){
        console.log("PHP responded with: " + response)
    }
}).fail(function(){
    console.log("Fail")
})
```

})

PHP

```
echo "Test";
```

The fail function is not triggering, but the succes function never prints anything. I can console.log data before and after the ajax. Can you help me find the problem? Thanks.

Comment: And I am aware of that I am not using the post_data for anything in the php file, but that is not the issue here. I would like the response "Test" to be printed in my jquery

Comment: I think ` succes: ` should be ` success: `

Comment: You are not preventing your form from posting/refreshing. try adding a `event.preventDefault();` inside `$('#form-comment').submit(function(event){ ... });`

Comment: Ah, that is something I was looking at as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error with the `success` word :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/handler-comment.php',
    type: "post",
    data: post_data,
    success: function(response){
        console.log("PHP responded with: " + response)
    }
}).fail(function(){
    console.log("Fail")
})
```